# Configuration of Redshift

Tags: gnome, configuration, ubuntu-gnome, redshift

I want to configure Redshift in such a manner such that it will be in the least brightness every time (irrespective whether it is day or night).

Also let me know if I might face any problem if I use it in such manner.

Comment: the settings options seem rather limited with redshift. If you want a permanent setting, why not set it with xrandr?

Comment: @dhanvi - Do you mean how to keep all of Redshift's settings the same both day and night, so the screen color/temperature does not change, or specifically the brightness?

Comment: @JacobVlijm can you help me or give me some links which can achieve same as redshift which changes the colour of screen to red so that it doesn't hurt my eyes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What RedShift does

After a little research, it turns out RedShift changes the colour temperature of your screen. Using xrandr instead, as I suggested in my comment to your question, would not have the same effect. With xrandr, you can only set gamma and brightness.

#### Using RedShift from command line

The GUI of RedShift has very limited options, and you can not set the color temperature in a permanent way. However, Redshift also has some command line options: open in a terminal window: `redshift -h` to see the options.

Simply running the command:

```
redshift -O 3700
```

Will set your screen permanently to "night".

Neutral temperature is:

```
redshift -O 6500
```

Adding the (first) command to your Startup Applications will apply the setting on log in.
(Dash > Startup Applications > Add)

Comment: https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/127#issuecomment-60466590 can you look into this one please